# Dart Get Request With Azure Subscription Key As Header

Tags: dart

I’m trying to modify my existing function to include a header which is Azure subscription key. Here’s my code:

```
Future<Response> read({required String url, Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters}) async {
    try {
      log.info('URI: ${Uri.http(baseUrlStr, _generateUnencodedPath(url), queryParameters)}');
      final http.Response httpResponse =
          await http.get(Uri.http(baseUrlStr, _generateUnencodedPath(url), queryParameters));
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = {
        ...jsonDecode(httpResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>,
        ...{'statusCode': httpResponse.statusCode}
      };
      final Response response = Response.fromJson(responseJson);
      return response;
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('No Internet Connection');
    }
  }
```